# ggplotly ignores "linetype" aesthetic of geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, ggplotly, aesthetics

How to make `plotly::ggplotly` correctly render/print linetypes when using ggplot2 `geom_bar`?

Here is a reproductible exemple:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# this shows the problem
static_plot = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = rownames(mtcars), y = mpg, linetype=as.character(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = NA, color = "black")
print(static_plot) # see that here we have different linetypes as expected

ggplotly(static_plot) # the lines are all the same i.e continuous!
```

**output from `print(static_plot)` with expected linetypes:**

[image: output from print() with expected linetypes]

**ouput from `ggplotly(static_plot)`; linetype aesthetic has not been taken into account**

[image: ouput from <code>ggplotly()</code>]

```
# using a geom_line it works fine
static_plot2 = ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, linetype=as.character(cyl))) +
  geom_line(color = "black")
print(static_plot2)

ggplotly(static_plot2)
```

[image: working example with geom_line]

Maybe this is obvious but I can't find the trick to do it...

Comment: Probably a bug. Report it to the package maintainer.

Comment: I agree, and I could reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have never done this before. Is there a place to do so? I will make some researches but if you have a link to a tutorial it is very welcome.

Comment: See there under "BugReports": https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/index.html